# android- half image background gets black

Tags: android, eclipse

i have image views in my Dialog Layout, But Half of Two Of Them Gets Black when running (All Images Are png Format)

[image]

Here Is the XML layout Code for this part:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_72sdp"
    android:divider="@drawable/linearspace"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/staroff" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/staron" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/staroff" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/staron" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/staroff" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/staron" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the code for all 3 images are the same but just one of them looks fine.

Comment: I guess you are using gif image. am i right?

Comment: @Masum No it is PNG format

Comment: Do you do something programmatically?

Comment: @DamiaFuentess Yes, i Set the Image resource, 
`star1.setImageResource(R.drawable.staron);`
(the resource is same as what it is Now)